# Can't get info from hcidump --raw output

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, ibeacon, bluez, hci

i am trying to create a BLE scan module via nodeJs and Bluez. I want to learn how to get mac address, minor, major and rssi values from the output of `hcidump --raw` command. I took a look at Radius Networks ibeacon_scan file but i still don't have a clue how i can do it with nodeJs. Can anyone help me with that? Thanks a lot

Comment: Am not sure about hcidump, did you tried using "btmon"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `sudo hcidump -R -x`

Then in a second terminal do your Bluetooth stuff